# PHP: Check if dynamically added file upload is empty

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

I have a form where users can add text and optional file. There's "Add more" button, which will add a new set of text and file upload. Text is required, but the file is not.

The problem comes when users don't select a file in the middle. For example, they add text and select a file. They click *add more*, and they only add text. In the third line, they add both text and file.

This is returned as an array. In this example, the text array will have 3 elements, and the file array will have 2. Is there a way to know that the second file upload doesn't have any files? Is there any other way to "connect" text with files? I'm open to any suggestions. Maybe to modify the front-end in some way?

Comment: I asume you use `name="file[]"` in your html, you could use `name="file[0]"` instead.

Comment: the short answer is "name your inputs correctly"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roland Starke's comment has resolved my problem. I've added the numbering to the name of the upload and text fields, which resolved my problem.

I have been using name="file[]", and replaced this with name="file[0]", so I'm now able to check if specific upload file is